# How to convert .raw file video format to avi or mp4?

Tags: video, video-conversion, raw, camera-raw

I want to convert the raw format to any other format. Is there any software for it? I download more than 10 software. But it doesn't support .raw file type to convert

Comment: You could always use ffmpeg...

Comment: @td512 what do you mean ffmpeg

Comment: You can try [SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) which uses most of the freely available encoders and decoders to see if it can read or convert it.  But as Robbie said, RAW files do not have to conform to a standard, so these files may not be readable by anything besides what comes from the camera manufacturer.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

RAW files do not have a standard format and may require proprietary software so it's difficult to answer your question accurately without knowing what created the file.

The Wikipedia page on Raw Image Format does suggest some software that may read RAW files such as [dcraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dcraw) and [darktable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darktable).

Comment: the copied file it shows `.raw` type. Can't it be converted to any format?